# Case-insensitive keywords with boost::spirit::lex

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, case-insensitive, boost-spirit-lex

Is there a way to recognize specific patterns case-insensitively?

E.g. if I have

```
literal_bool = L"True|False";
this->self.add(literal_bool, TokenId_LiteralBool);
```

How can I match `true`, `TRUE`, `tRuE` while avoiding to write `[Tt][Rr][Uu][Ee]` for each keyword?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Regular expressions supported by `boost::spirit::lex`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/lex/quick_reference/lexer.html) include a case-sensitivity control:

> `(?r-s:pattern)`
>
> apply option 'r' and omit option 's' while interpreting pattern.
>   Options may be zero or more of the characters `'i'` or `'s'`. `'i'`
>   means case-insensitive. `'-i'` means case-sensitive. `'s'` alters the
>   meaning of the '`.`' syntax to match any single character whatsoever.
>   `'-s'` alters the meaning of '`.`' to match any character except
>   '`\n`'.

Thus you can write:

```
literal_bool = L"(?i:true|false)";
this->self.add(literal_bool, TokenId_LiteralBool);
```

---

**Original answer**

Introduce a function that makes a pattern case insensitive:

```
literal_bool = L"True|False";
this->self.add(make_case_insensitive(literal_bool), TokenId_LiteralBool);
```

Implementation for regular (non-wide) strings:

```
std::string make_case_insensitive(const std::string& s)
{
    std::string r;
    std::string cC = "[xX]";
    for(char c : s)
    {
        if ( std::isalpha(c) )
        {
            cC[1] = std::tolower(c);
            cC[2] = std::toupper(c);
            r += cC;
        }
        else
            r += c;
    }
    return r;
}
```